# How to unpack xlsx?

Tags: excel-2007

I would like to work with internal .xlsx files (styles.xml). I was using `<oXygen/>` to navigate through internal structure, but now it is throwing an error.

How to unpack xlsx files (and then pack them again)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unzip the file

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a mac, use the command-line `unzip` instead of the one built into Finder.  I had the same headache until I switch to CLI.

Comment: Your answer does not relate to the OP's question. You could clarify how to generally pack and unpack XLSX files or point out problems when doing so with Finders integrated ZIP-Tool.

Comment: Honestly, I was trying to provide clarification to the user above who couldn't get the file dismantled on their mac and it the system wouldn't let me comment.

Comment: @Tor. N. Johnson, I appreciate your answer - I would appreciate it even more if you provided what I should be putting into terminal to execute this unzipping.

Comment: @Kat: put your-file-name.xlsx into an empty directory. Open a terminal window in that directory, then type: unzip your-file-name.xlsx.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in Windows:

Rename your file something.xlsx => something.xlsx.zip - you can then access it with File Explorer.